# How to perform raster scan of the curses screen to the file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ncurses

I am creating one call flow based on the content from one input file to the curses screen (window). I could successfully create the call flow to the curses screen. I would like to perform the raster scan of the curses screen and to write into the output file which i am giving.  Could you please help in this regards. 
Please find the python code snippet below.

```css
#! /usr/bin/python2.6
import sys, getopt
import curses
from curses import wrapper

def call(stdscr):
        inputFile = ''
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
            print 'my_box.py -i <inputFile_With_Path>'
            sys.exit(2)
        for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt == '-h':
                print 'my_box.py -i <inputFile_With_Path>'
                sys.exit()
            elif opt == '-i':
                inputFile = arg

        output_file = open("/home/vparamasivam/Training/Python/n.txt", "wb+")
        my_Dict = { }
        cur_y = 3
        cur_sbc = 30
        cur_EP1 = 10
        cur_uas = 50
        cur_UAC = 10
        sbc_cur = 24
        cur_poi = 2
        RED_TEXT = 1
        endPointCount = 0
        callCount = 0
        count = 0
        if not curses.has_colors():
            curses.endwin()
            print "no colors"
            sys.exit()
        else:
            curses.start_color()

        curses.init_pair(RED_TEXT, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

        window = curses.newwin(1500, 1500, 0, 0)

        fo = open(inputFile, "r");

        print "Name of the file :", fo.name
        print "File closed or not :", fo.closed


        window.addstr(1, 29, "SBC", curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
        window.vline(cur_y, cur_sbc, '|', 1500)
        for line in fo:
            if (line.find("Receive Msg From:") != -1) :
                ip, l, p, s, msg = line.split(',')
                ipc, ip = ip.rsplit(' ',1)
                ip, port = ip.split('/')
                ipPort = ip + ':' + port
                s, msg, req_uri = msg.split(' ', 2)
                print "\n SIP message : ", msg, ' '
                print "Received from IP : ", ipPort, ' '
                callCount += 1
                if not my_Dict.has_key(ipPort):
                    endPointCount +=1
                    if endPointCount == 1:
                        window.addstr(1, 4, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_EP1, '|', 1500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_EP1}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_EP1 += 7
                        cur_poi += 1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        cur_EP1 -= 6
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '-', 18)
                        cur_EP1 += 18
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '>')
                    else :
                        sbc_cur +=20
                        if endPointCount != 2:
                            cur_uas +=20
                        window.addstr(1, sbc_cur, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_uas, '|', 1500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_uas}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=2
                        cur_uas -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_uas +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '<')
                        count = cur_uas - cur_sbc - 1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_sbc -=2
                else :
                    ep = my_Dict[ipPort]
                    if ep == cur_UAC :
                        ep += 7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        ep -= 6
                        window.hline(cur_poi, ep, '-', 18)
                        ep += 18
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '>')
                        cur_poi += 1
                    else :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        ep +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '<')
                        count = ep - cur_sbc - 1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_sbc -=2

            elif (line.find("Send Msg to:") != -1) :
                ip, l, p, s, msg = line.split(',')
                s, msg, status = msg.split(' ', 2)
                ipc, ip = ip.rsplit(' ',1)
                ip, port = ip.split('/')
                ipPort = ip + ':' + port
                print "\n SIP message : ", msg, ' '
                print "Sent to IP : ", ipPort, ' '
                callCount += 1
                if not my_Dict.has_key(ipPort):
                    endPointCount +=1
                    if endPointCount == 1:
                        window.addstr(1, 9, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_EP1, '|', 1500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_EP1}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_EP1 +=7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_EP1 -=6
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '<')
                        cur_EP1 +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '-', 18)
                    else :
                        sbc_cur +=20
                        if endPointCount != 2:
                            cur_uas +=20
                        window.addstr(1, sbc_cur, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_uas, '|', 1500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_uas}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_uas -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_uas +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        count = cur_uas - cur_sbc - 1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_uas -=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, '>')
                        cur_uas +=1
                        cur_sbc -=1
                else :
                    ep = my_Dict[ipPort]
                    if ep == cur_UAC :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep +=7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        ep -= 6
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '<')
                        ep +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, ep, '-', 18)
                        cur_poi += 1
                    else :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        ep +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        count = ep - cur_sbc - 1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        ep -=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '>')
                        cur_sbc -=1

        inchar = window.getch()
  
        ''' Place where i want to perfomr raster scan of the curses screen '''

def main(stdscr):

    call(stdscr)

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: @Jim Dennis Could you please help in this regards.

Comment: A *raster scan* is done outside the scope of curses, being the **bitmap** image of the window.